# Brake pads Discs rotation

Tags: ford

Had some  vibration on a turn wheel  while  pressing  my  brake     Mechanic Shop  told me  i need  to replace my  front pods and discs , Took it to a  Pep  boys  for a second opinion and they said pods are  fine for at least a year   just  need to  turn  my discs   57k miles on truck  never got any  brake  service   what's  the deal

Comment: Discs are not "rotated" as you might do with tires.  Either you misunderstood them or they are idiots.  It's not uncommon for brake rotors to warp as they wear out and that's possibly what you're feeling when turning and braking.  But then it make also be  wheel bearings which can generate the same sort of vibration as brakes.  I'm guessing you're not mechanically inclined enough to take on a repair like this on your own.  Go back to the original mechanic, who I assume you trust, and have them do the needed work.

Answer (score 1):

Did they say rotate your discs or did they say "turn" your discs. Turning means machining.

Comment: yes  Turning  is corect

Comment: They can be turned in place on the car